# General rule for $(A \land B) \lor (\neg A \land D)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I encountered the following small expression: 
$$
(n\ge0\land y \gt 5) \lor(n \lt 0  \land x > 10).  
$$
The answer should be easily $(x > 10 \land y \gt 5)$ but unfortunately I don't see how the components get factored out in a way to exploit the tautology $n\ge0 \lor n\lt 0 = true$ and simplify the expression.
I tried to use the distributive law but I got a longer and worse expression. 
Maybe there is a general proven formula to back up the computation in these cases?

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(x > 10 \lor y > 5)?$

Comment: Mh it may be. Would you be so kind to tell me which rules did you apply in order to get there?

Comment: I just say, one of the statements $n\ge0$ and $n<0$ must be true so one of the two clauses must be true.  In the first case,$x>10.$  In the second, $y>5.$  I don't think there's much use for symbolic logic in ordinary reasoning.  However, you can apply the distributives laws a couple of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposition $(n\ge0\land y \gt 5) \lor(n \lt 0  \land x > 10)$ is **not** equivalent to $(x > 10 \lor y \gt 5)$.

For example, take $n=0$, $x=11$ and $y=0$.

However, it is true that $(n\ge0\land y \gt 5) \lor(n \lt 0  \land x > 10)$  **implies** $(x > 10 \lor y \gt 5)$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
(A \land B) \lor (\lnot A \land C) &\iff (A \lor \lnot A) \land (A \lor C) \land (B \lor \lnot A) \land (B \lor C) \\ &\iff (A \lor C) \land (\lnot A \lor B) \land (B \lor C)
\end{align*}
It's not hard to see that this implies $B \lor C$ but it is not equivalent to $B \lor C$.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the cases $A = true$ and $\neg A = true$ and compare the truth values of these statements. So your answer should actually say $ x > 10 \vee y > 5$.

Comment: What if $A$ and $C$ are true, while $B$ is false ? Then the expression $(A \wedge B) \vee (\lnot A \wedge C)$ is false but $B \vee C$ is true.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I should have said implication instead. I have edited my comment.